# Getting either value or index number from a set

Tags: python

I have the following two lists:

```
list_1 = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'EFG']
list_2 = ['TESTABC', 'TESTDWQ', 'TESTEFG', 'TEST123', 'TEST345']
```

I am using the following code in order to check if anything in `list_1` is actually in `list_2`:

```
check_list = set([item for item in list_1 for things in list_2 if item in things])
```

Now it works fine, it is able to tell me what it finds:

```
ABC
EFG
```

but it doesn't give me the whole value, which I am trying to get it to output:

```
TESTABC
TESTEFG
```

Is there a way to get the index or even better actually print out the value when it finds something?

Comment: Keep `things` not `item`? `set([things for item in list_1 for things in list_2 if item in things])`

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `item` with `things`

```
set([things for item in list_1 for things in list_2 if item in things])
```

To reduce it to one loop

```
import re
[i for i in list_2 if re.match("\w*("+'|'.join(list_1)+")$",i)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help mad_ and yatu, really appreciate it. But just curious is there a way to print only the value when i try to print check_list it just prints it out as "set(['TESTABC']) is there a way to only print TESTABC

Comment: `list(set(['TESTABC']))` gives you `['TESTABC']`

Comment: @Mr39 `set` is still a iterable so you can just iterate over to get the items or convert it into a `list`

Answer (score 0):

My take on problem, using `re`:

```
l1 = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'EFG']
l2 = '''TESTABC
TESTDWQ
TESTEFG
TEST123
TEST345'''

import re

s = re.findall('|'.join(f'(?:^.*{i}.*)' for i in l1), l2, flags=re.M)
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
['TESTABC', 'TESTEFG']
```